# In OpenJdk how do I set font dir with appendedfontpath property

Tags: fonts, java

I am trying to get my application to use fonts from a particular location in an OpenJdk installation using *appendedfontpath* property but it is not working for me.

```
../jre1.8.0_121+1/bin/java  -Dappendedfontpath=/usr/lib/fonts/  -jar lib/songkong-4.7.jar -m /mnt/disk1/share
```

reporting no fonts installed, but the /usr/lib/fonts folder does contain a font `ipag.ttf`

Please Note:

- OpenJdk comes with no preinstalled fonts it relies on fonts installed on system
- This is an embedded system that reports no fonts installed on server, `fc-list` returns nothing
- If I copy the font into jre/lib/fonts folder it works but I'm not allowed to copy anything into this folder.
- Nor am I allowed to run root commands such as `fc-cache -f`

If I could get it working by just specifying a font folder containing fonts, it would be a working solution for me.

Comment: Hi can you you grab any info out of the following path, if it exists, `JavaHome/lib/fontconfig.OS.properties`

Comment: The file doesnt exist

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set the `JAVA_FONTS` enviroment variable befor starting the JVM to make it aware of the directory path.
For your case this could be done by `export JAVA_FONTS=/usr/lib/fonts`.
My answer is based on the [Java Runtime Enviroment fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts#TrueType_fonts) article of the archlinux wiki.

---

EDIT:
Test in a VM with no Fonts installed show that setting JAVA_FONTS does not work
and I have come to the conclusion that with your setup it might not be possible to achieve your goal.
I used the following Program to reproduce the error on a VM with no Fonts installed:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class example{

    public static void main(String[] tArgs){
        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        j.add(new JButton("Test"));
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.pack();
   }

}
```

Here is my Stacktrace:
https://pastebin.com/fy3JDnkN
Given the source of the [X11FontManager](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/sun/awt/X11FontManager.java)
the error occurs while the Font Manager is constructed in the line with `for (int i=0; i<fontConfigFonts.length; i++) {`.

```
public String[] getDefaultPlatformFont() {
    if (defaultPlatformFont != null) {
        return defaultPlatformFont;
    }
    String[] info = new String[2];
    getFontConfigManager().initFontConfigFonts(false);
    FontConfigManager.FcCompFont[] fontConfigFonts =
        getFontConfigManager().getFontConfigFonts();
    for (int i=0; i<fontConfigFonts.length; i++) {
        if ("sans".equals(fontConfigFonts[i].fcFamily) &&
            0 == fontConfigFonts[i].style) {
            info[0] = fontConfigFonts[i].firstFont.familyName;
            info[1] = fontConfigFonts[i].firstFont.fontFile;
            break;
        }
    }
    /* Absolute last ditch attempt in the face of fontconfig problems.
     * If we didn't match, pick the first, or just make something
     * up so we don't NPE.
     */
    if (info[0] == null) {
        if (fontConfigFonts.length > 0 &&
            fontConfigFonts[0].firstFont.fontFile != null) {
            info[0] = fontConfigFonts[0].firstFont.familyName;
            info[1] = fontConfigFonts[0].firstFont.fontFile;
        } else {
            info[0] = "Dialog";
            info[1] = "/dialog.ttf";
        }
    }
    defaultPlatformFont = info;
    return defaultPlatformFont;
}
```

This makes it impossible to add Fonts Manually since the NullPointerException occurs prior to us having access to the Font Manager, this behavior seams to not be intended given the comment a couple lines later.

It might still be possible to achieve your goal if there is another FontManager for Linux that does not crash with no default System Font installed, but I could not find such a replacement.

Comment: Is there any way I can add this as a -D option when I invoke java

Comment: The only -D option I can find would be `prism.fontdir` which is mentiond in the [OpenJDK wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Font+Setup/#FontSetup-EnablingcustomEmbeddedfonts), but it looks like it's OpenJFX specific.

Comment: I tried -DJAVA_FONTS=/usr/lib/fonts and export JAVA_FONTS=/usr/lib/fonts and neither worked I dont think its actually understand by openjdk

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to pack fonts in your own jar and try to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728006/using-font-from-my-jar).

Comment: Trouble is its not my code that ever requires a font, its a third party library that requires it hence I never have the chance to provide it with a Font instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the font directory. If it is installed in your machine, the JRE will pick the fonts automatically.

I was also facing this issue in the past and found a pre-built open JRE packages with fonts in github. These packages are released under GNU GPL v. 2 with classpath exception.

https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/tag/1.8.0.121-1

You can download the Linux version (java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64.zip) or else you can look for updates other than 121 as well under releases.

Note: You can also include the missing True Type fonts under jre/lib/fonts if required.

> Alternate Option I

Installing the required fonts in your machine. This will work seamlessly and you don't have to configure anything in the JRE.

Note:

- If you don't have privilege to install fonts, you can very well copy
  the fonts /usr/share/fonts directory.
- If it is a read-only partition, you can mount the partition in read-write mode and copy the font files.
- In case if there is no space left in the partition where /usr/share/fonts belongs to, you can copy the files in a different directory and make a soft link to it.

> Alternate Option II

Including the fonts in jre/lib/fonts directory (create fonts directory if not exists) and configuring the fontconfig.properties file in jre/lib. I haven't tested this option but it should work.

> Edit:

- If fonts are already installed in the machine, JVM should pick the fonts automatically. Otherwise you can specify the fonts as mentioned in **@BdoubleB97** answer using JAVA_FONTS environment variable.
- If you don't have permission to set the environment variable, you can pass the environment variable during run time as below.

  ./java -DJAVA_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts Test

Comment: As I say the machine already has a font in  /usr/lib/fonts but Java is not finding this. I'm not allowed to copy fonts to /usr/share/fonts and Im not allowed to create jre/lib/fonts or create fontconfig.properties in jre lib. So y question remains can I either load these fonts as a part of my application so they can be found by any part of the code that requires font (without making code changes) or why doesnt -Dappendedfontpath work

Comment: If fonts are already installed in your machine, you can use the environment variable as suggested by @BdoubleB97. The environment variable can be passed with -D option as well. Added this option in the above answer as well.

Comment: I tried -DJAVA_FONTS=/usr/lib/fonts and export JAVA_FONTS=/usr/lib/fonts and neither worked I don't think this environment is actually understand by openjdk

Answer (score 0):

The standard system location for fonts is /usr/share/fonts and subdirectories (see fontconfig & `# fc-cache -f`). /usr/lib/fonts is one of the miriad non-standard locations which have been deprecated ~ 14 years ago, that's why the system and OpenJDK can't find your fonts.

Unlike legacy SUN JVMs OpenJDK actually tries to integrate with the system and use system resources (not only under Windows).

Comment: But the fonts on my system are not in /usr/share/fonts so how can i get openjdk to work without modifying the system

Comment: Long term? You can't. Standards have a way of stream-rolling non-standard because no one wants to invest in one-of-a-kind maintenance. Short term you can try all sorts of evil kludges from symlinks to /usr/share/fonts, installing in ~/.fonts, adding default search directories to /etc/fonts/fonts.conf or ~/.fonts/fonts.conf. But it will all be miserable to test and have a limited shelf-life. Blame whoever thought installing fonts in a non-standard location on your system was a good idea.

Comment: No I blame openjdk for being inflexible in this respect. Why not provide some standard fonts like Oracle Java does or support the -DJAVA_FONTS option so it can cope better with awkward systems. I cannot do any of those kludges you mention because I am not allowed to modify anything on the system

Comment: It is the nature of standards to enable growth, lower costs and complexity by removing flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

### How to specify font dirs:

**Tested on OpenJDK 11 And 17**

1. lib/fontconfig.properties set appendedfontpath=ADDITIONAL_FONT_PATH.
2. -Dsun.java2d.fontpath=append:FONT_PATH|prepend:FONT_PATH

Tips: at least step 2 are **required** to make sure FontConfiguration active.

### How to install fonts for java

1. jre/lib/fonts
2. System Font dir (Eg: Windows: C:\Windows\Fonts)
3. specify additional font dir to JDK/JRE as above.

note: if change mapping relations between logical fonts and physical fonts, we need to edit fontconfig.properties

### Ref

[Font Configuration File - Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/intl/font-configuration-files.html#GUID-1F5136AF-907B-4C64-8657-73D953D7B912)